# -[__NSArrayM setTableViewStyle:]: error while creating a custom uitablevewcell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

I've just created a custom cell in a tableview, I called the custom cell in UITableViewDelegate method

```
--(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

This is what my code looks like:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

        static NSString *cellId = @"cellIdetifier";
        static NSString *cellId2 = @"cellId2";

        tableCell *customCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId2];
        if(customCell == nil){

            NSArray *customObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"tableCell" owner:self options:nil];
            for(id obj in customObjects){

                if([obj isKindOfClass:[tableCell class]]){

                    customCell = (tableCell *)customObjects;
                    break;
                }

            }


        }

        return customCell;

}
```

I'm getting a error which says

```
 creatingcustomcell[693:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM setTableViewStyle:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6d6c7f0'
```

Please help me, I have no clue what has just happened.

Comment: where do you use `setTableViewStyle` method?

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to tell from this code if your coersion in line:

```
 customCell = (tableCell *)customObjects;
```

is correct. At least it looks strange that you coerce an array:

```
NSArray *customObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"tableCell" owner:self options:nil];
```

to your `tableCell`

Do you mean:

```
 customCell = (tableCell *)obj;
```

Also you might want to follow the recommendation that class names should be capitalized

Answer (score 0):

```
 if([obj isKindOfClass:[tableCell class]]){
      customCell = (tableCell *)customObjects;
      break;
 }
```

You are setting the cell to the entire array

Do this instead

```
 for (int i=0; i < customObjects.count; i++) {

     if([customObjects objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[tableCell class]]){

          customCell = (tableCell *)[customObjects objectAtIndex:i];
          break;
     }
}
```

Comment: There are easier ways to use a custom cell BTW than doing this. That will fix you though.